# An integral including the complete elliptic integral

Tags: definite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

Let $\lambda>1$, $0<\alpha<\pi$, how to evaluate:
$$I=\int_0^\pi K\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\sin\theta\sin\alpha}{\lambda-cos(\theta+\alpha)}}\right)\frac{\sin\theta\cos\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{\lambda-cos(\theta+\alpha)}}$$
Where $K$ is the complete elliptic integral.
Let $$u=\sqrt{\frac{2\sin\theta\sin\alpha}{\lambda-\cos(\theta+\alpha)}}$$
then:
$$du=\frac{2\sin\alpha}{u}\frac{cos\theta(\lambda-cos(\theta+\alpha))-sin\theta\sin(\theta+\alpha)}{(\lambda-cos(\theta+\alpha))^2}d\theta=\frac{2\sin\alpha}{u}\frac{\lambda cos\theta-cos\alpha}{(\lambda-cos(\theta+\alpha))^2}d\theta$$
Therefore:
$$du=\frac{\lambda cos\theta-cos\alpha}{u}\frac{u^4}{2\sin\alpha\sin^2\theta}d\theta$$
or:
$$d\theta=\frac{2\sin\alpha}{u^3}\frac{\sin^2\theta}{\lambda cos\theta-cos\alpha}du$$
....